# Stopping the ParticleSystem from running all the time

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

How do you stop the ParticleSystem that you have inserted as a Game Object in your Scene from running all the time?

I have a little ideas only and they don't yet work.

So let's say I have a "ParticleSystem3" named Game Object in my Hierarchy of objects - what is the correct way to reference the ParticleSystem3 and stop it from continuous emitting?

I don't understand the examples I found when they don't seem to give me a correct reference to the ParticleSystem.

I know there is a Play, a Pause and a Stop functions in the manual under the ParticleSystem headline. How to use them correctly? I would need only the Stop and so my question is the mechanism of Stop related to the ParticleSystem as I already mentioned.

I am coding this in either JS (JavaScript) or C#.

Do you have any tips other than "Google it"? I don't find the answer, it seems, and I am a newbie to the Unity3d 5.2.

Comment: I tried these: (numbers to clarify the order, 1-4 in this tryout as a whole) 1. public ParticleSystem exp; 2. var exp = gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>(); 3. var temp = exp.emission; 4. temp.enabled = false; for me these didn't do anything visible

Comment: Check out the answer, should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Disable the GameObject with the ParcileSystem, but I quess it is not what you are looking for, as you want the GameObject to be active.
2. `gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().enableEmission = false;`
3. `gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Stop();`

When you want the ParticleSystem, to emmit again:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().enableEmission = true;

gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look this soon.

Comment: I don't get this board's function related to answers but as I stated hm above yes, I am still trying to set the ParticleSystem to stop or something. Clues here didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but it does not seem to stop the continuously emitting ParticleSystem. Other suggestions are welcome. If I find the answer, I might post it here.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{

    if(col.gameObject.tag == "bomb")
    {
        // I got hit by a bomb! 
        Instantiate(explosion, col.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        //ParticleSystem temp = ParticleSystem2;
        //temp.emission.enabled = false;
        ParticleSystem.EmissionModule em = ParticleSystem2.emission; 
        em.enabled = false;
        ParticleSystem2.Stop ();

        gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().enableEmission = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Stop();
```

Then after a couple hours, I made an empty Scene with a ParticleSystem Game Object below Main Camera, and attached a Script to the ParticleSystem. This was the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().enableEmission = false;
    gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Stop();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().enableEmission = false;
    //gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Stop();
}
```

}

Now it worked.